# Getting blank image from Binary Thresholding function of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, image-analysis

Why do I end up with a blank image every time I run the [Binary Thresholding](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/binary-thresholding-function.htm) function of ArcGIS Pro on this single band image (Landsat 8, band 4)?

I've run into the same issue before with other raster tools, and changing little things in the symbology like changing the stretch type from percent clip to standard deviation fixed it. But this time I can't seem to resolve the issue and don't know what else to try.

To make sure I was going through the process correctly I used a different but similar image and it worked correctly.

[image: Image of binary Thresholding Issue]